# wpf scrollviewer dialogbox

Tags: wpf, modal-dialog, scrollviewer

I have a question about WPF's ScrollViewer

This is the code I currently have:

```
<Window x:Class="BasketNovelEditor.Menu.AboutBox"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterOwner"
    Title="AboutBox" Height="Auto" Width="425" Focusable="True" SizeToContent="Height">
<Grid>     
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="200"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Label Grid.Row="0" MinHeight="50" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center">Thank you!</Label>
    <Label Grid.Row="1" MinHeight="30" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center">BasketNovel uses the following Libraries:</Label>
    <Button Grid.Row="3" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" IsDefault="True" IsCancel="True">Close Window</Button>
    <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="2" Margin="5" Height="200">
        <StackPanel>

        </StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

And these are the results I'm getting:

http://i1280.photobucket.com/albums/a500/daegon123/ss.png

http://i1280.photobucket.com/albums/a500/daegon123/ss_zps3d6b8c90.png

I have absolutely no idea why my scrollbar is showing up like this.
I was at least expecting the up/down arrows to be placed at the start/end points
of the scrollbar.

Anyone have a clue as to why this is happening?
I'm not sure if this has anything to do with it, but the Window is 
being used as a dialog box called as follows:

aboutbox.ShowDialog();

I'm currently using .NET 4.0

--EDIT2--

After a bit of testing, I realised that this would happen in all my modal windows
if I placed scrollviewers in them. The scrollviewer in my main window looks fine,
so I'm getting the feeling this is something modal window specific, or something
I may be doing to them without knowing. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Looks fine for me if I paste your code in a normal WPF window. Are there any global styles or something like that in your application?

Comment: No, just the main window and that bit of code up there for my dialog box. Any other thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried moving the Height="200" to the StackPanel instead?

Comment: Just tried, with no apparent change. The thing is I'd understand if my scrollbar wasn't appearing at all or if only the up arrow was showing, but to have the up/down arrows stuck together at the top like that is really getting beyond any estimations I can make

Comment: It's understandable in the StackPanel (going against my answer), as - unlike most other panels - it expands based on its contents. I always thought the ScrollViewer is just a wrapper for the child element. You could probably use another panel between the ScrollViewer and StackPanel with a fixed height to make it work, such as a DockPanel.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've tried replacing the StackPanel with a DockPanel with fixed height, but I'm still having the same issue - this time also with the Textbox I've placed within the scrollviewer (please see the code edit I've put up)

Comment: I actually meant put the StackPanel as a child of the DockPanel. But, to be honest, your layout is fairly strange. Instead of using multiple Grid rows, just use one with fixed positions. Or use a StackPanel with appropriate margins, and wrap the whole thing in a ScrollViewer. I reckon that would work better, and look better too :)

Comment: Thanks for the continuous replies. I've made the layout change you recommended and it definitely looks a whole lot better. I'm still getting the deformed scrollbar though, and after testing, I realised this would happen in all the other modal windows I'm using if I place scrollviewers within them. The scrollviewer on my main window works fine, so I'm starting to wonder if this is something modal window specific. Any ideas..?

Answer (score 0):

This for some reason has been resolved after an update to Visual Studio 2012 update2.

I'm still using .NET 4.0

Answer (score 0):

Encountered with the same problem in 2019, with VS2019 Community. ScrollViewer worked just fine in Main Window, but in Modal Window it doesn't scroll at all.

I set Height to the ScrollViewer and to the StackPanel, and it start worked fine.

```
<ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" PanningMode="Both" Height="340">
```

Also I played with different versions of .NET Framework